# My select sum query returns 0 even though I have values in my database

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

```
    $this->db->select_sum('quantity');
    $query = $this->db->get('products');
    return $query->result();
```

I don't get it why my code returns a value of 0 even though my column has values in it and when I try putting price instead of quantity it works.

Database structure:

```
Name              Type               Null        Default 
price             decimal(25,4)       No          None
quantity          decimal(15,4)       Yes         0.0000
```

Database:

```
id         name          price          quantity
1          Sample1      10.0000          0.0000
2          Sample2      0.0000           45.0000
```

Comment: Please add your database structure & tables. Make sure your quantity is an Interger data.

Comment: please see edited post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code.

```
$this->db->select_sum('quantity', 'qty');
$query = $this->db->get('products');
return $query->row();
```

Add this to your views.

```
$total_quantity = $this->yourmodel->modelfunction()->qty;
```

If still can't run, you need to provide more data for us like your views and table examples. You need to give more data for ask, if you won't others see your data. You can give an example with same data.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: It works ? Because I don't know how you called it in your views. Make sure if you just call 1 rows of data from your database, use `row()` dont use `result()`.

Comment: Sure, you must call `$total_quantity = $this->yourmodel->function();` and to avoid error i'll fix the answers